# Not able to install cordova-plugin-accountkit

Tags: ios, cordova, npm, ionic3, account-kit

I am trying to install cordova-plugin-accountkit in my Ionic v3 app . It worked fine in Android but now showing this error in iOS.

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-accountkit':undefined Error:
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in
>   `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.

Answer (score 0):

what command are you using to install accountkit?

**if you are using sudo try without it**.

Comment: Without sudo it is giving persmission denied error !